# Would Lego Mindstorm projects be off topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Would it be appropriate to ask about [Lego Mindstorm](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/default.aspx) programming questions? If you do not know, Mindstorm uses a drag and drop programming language to use in Lego robots. I am wondering because since it uses a drag n drop interface, it may be degraded, but it has a lot of programming logic in it like loops, switch, data manipulators, input/output, etc.

Comment: [tag:mindstorms] tag on [so]

Comment: Seems like the discussion is taking place here: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mindstorms

Comment: Perhaps [Robotics.se]? But programming questions are perfectly on-topic for [so]

Comment: @hjpotter92 That would probably be a good place for questions on that subject that go beyond just code/programming, i.e. questions mostly focusing on the general algorithms or high level approaches for solving problems, rather than how to translate those algorithms into something a machine can understand.

Comment: @SchautDollar I don't think it's degraded for being a block programming language, some industrial PLCs are too, I just think your changes for getting a specific response is better in the suggested site than stackoverflow, but I don't think its off-topic too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you want an answer from...

- ...Programmers? Ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mindstorms).
- ...Robotics engineers? Ask on [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mindstorms).
- ...Lego(R) enthusiasts? Ask on [LEGO(R)](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mindstorms).

Naturally, there's some overlap. But it should be reasonably easy to decide based on what you're *doing* with Mindstorms and what sort of expertise you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It's still programming, so yes, it's on topic.

There is even a tag ([mindstorms](/questions/tagged/mindstorms)) on the topic with several existing questions.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento 1) Even if there were another site that it is on topic for, that doesn't make it *off* topic on SO. 2) Such a site may be useful for non-programming questions related to that topic, or at least questions that include issues that may move beyond just the code.  That doesn't mean a question that *is* specific to just code doesn't exist and wouldn't fit just fine on SO.  When looking at defining a topic for such a newly created site it should look to find questions that *aren't* on topic on SO to be it's core topic.

Comment: If that was added, *and* the site became a graduated site then *perhaps* such questions would be considered offtopic here and migrated to that site.  Until both of those have happened it's certainly not appropriate to say that such a question is off topic.  As it is, I don't see enough demand there to justify implementing such a feature.